# How to use ng-repeat and show options with a conditions

Tags: angularjs

I want to know how to use ng-repeat and show only first option, the other ones are gonna be dependent of a button.

```
My code here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview
```

I want to show first option, the first select and input, the other options are gonna be hidden, and if i click the button, the option are gona appear, i am goint to save all option in an array, i will save the options as object.

```
userOp = [{}];
```

the limit of the ng-repeat is the number of options that can be selected, this way the user can select all diferents options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you need, you could have an Array with all the options you want to show and another array that starts empty and feeds the view. As your user selects the options you push the new step to the second array.

Controller

```
function OptionsCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    {text:'learn angular', select:['option1', 'option2', 'option3']},
    {text:'build an angular app', select:['another1', 'another2', 'another3', 'another4']},
    {text:'build an angular app', select:['onemore1', 'onemore2']}
  ];

  $scope.showNextOption = function(){
    var nextIndex = $scope.visibleOptions.length;
    if($scope.options.length > nextIndex)
    {
        $scope.results.push({input:'',select:''});
        $scope.visibleOptions.push($scope.options[nextIndex]);
    }else{
        // you can call $scope.save() here if you wish to save when the options have been presented
      // or just use the save button 
        console.log('save');
    }
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    //do whatever you need with $scope.results
    $scope.reset();
  }

  $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.visibleOptions = [];
    $scope.results = [];
        $scope.showNextOption(-1);
  }

  $scope.reset();

}
```

View

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Options</h2>
  <div ng-controller="OptionsCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="showNextOption()">
      <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="(index, option) in visibleOptions">
          <input type="text" ng-model="results[index]['input']" required>
          <select ng-model="results[index]['select']" required>
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="select in option.select" value="{{select}}">{{select}}</option>
          </select>
          <button
            type="submit"
            ng-show="visibleOptions.length == index+1 && visibleOptions.length < options.length">Next</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <button 
          ng-click="save()"
          ng-show="visibleOptions.length == options.length">Save</button>
    <br><br>
    {{
    results
    }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUm9x3WI36jTmsGNBpwD?p=preview)